# how to iterate a map in Groovyfx? keep getting errors! how can i solve this

Tags: javafx, groovy, groovyfx

I am new to the groovyfx part and i didn't understood how to keep iteration for map

can any one help me on this

thanks in advance

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart

import static groovyx.javafx.GroovyFX.start

final pieData = FXCollections.observableArrayList([new PieChart.Data("Yours", 42), new PieChart.Data("Mine", 58)])
def map = [
        'Firstpersonmarks' : 20,
        'secondpersonmarks' : 30,
        'thirdpersonmarks' : 40,
        'fourthpersonmarks' : 100
]
start {
    stage(title: 'GroovyFX Chart Demo', width: 1024, height: 960, visible: true) {
        scene {
            stackPane {
                scrollPane {
                    tilePane(padding: 10, prefTileWidth: 480, prefColumns: 2) {

                        map.each { println "Hex Code: $it.key = Color Name: $it.value" }

                        for (entry in map) {
                            println(data:[" $entry.key : $entry.value"])

                            pieChart(data: [" $entry.key : $entry.value"])
                        }
                        stackPane(alignment: TOP_RIGHT) {
                            pieChart(data: pieData, animated: true)
```

Comment: `keep getting errors!` Please post the errors your getting ;)

Comment: Try `map.each {key, value ->  println "Hex Code: {$key} = Color Name: ${value}" }`

Comment: Should be `"Hex Code: ${key}`

Comment: ya ok could you please help me on a little project i am building? @ou_ryperd